# Django - queryset split to 4, causes lots of hits to the database

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-database

Here is my template tag:

```
@register.filter
def split_to_4_columns(queryset):
    split = int(ceil(queryset.count()/4.))
    columns = list()
    for i in range(4):
        columns.append(queryset[i*split:(i+1)*split])
    return columns
```

And here is my pseudo usage in templates:

```
{% for column in queryset|split_to_4_columns %}
<div class="list">
    {% for object in column %}
    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" class="item">{{ object }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It basically splits my long querysets (few hundreds objects) into 4 columns for a better html presentation. But it also appears to hit hard on my database. First it evaluates the full queryset, and then every column gets it's own evaluation, how can I optimize it?

I am using caching, but still, I'd like to know how can I optimize it on a lower level than just caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you process all the data, at least one `select` returning all the data must be processed. To query data once, you can on first step request all the data (evaluate queryset) and on the second split it with pure python (not hitting DB):

```
@register.filter
def split_to_4_columns(queryset):
    values = list(queryset.all())
    split = int(ceil(len(values)/4.))
    columns = [values[i*split:(i+1)*split] for i in range(4)]
    return columns
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@register.filter
def split_to_4_columns(queryset):
    i = 0
    columns = [[],[],[],[],]
    for item in queryset:
        columns[i].append(item)
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
        else:
            i = i + 1

    return columns
```

Comment: this split differs with one used by OP; you can remove `if` condition with `i = (i + 1) % 4`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)?

```
{% for object in queryset %}
 {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
    <div class="list">
 {% endif %}
       <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" class="item">{{ object }}</a>
 {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
    </div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just noticed this answer. This is interesting approach. Why are there two identical ifs? When do I close the <div>?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Nah, still I don't think I understand this. It starts the list every 4 items. I want 4 divs, not queryset/4 divs. EDIT: completely lost, need a moment to test it :]

Comment: Nope, it's not what I wanted. But good to know there is this built in tag, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a few classes that help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
```