# Split Django Queryset in template for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model `Banner` with fields `image` and `name`. I need data from this model to be displayed in groups of three on a moving Bootstrap carousel.

My current implementation is the most expensive and simple one I could think of.

`banner1 = Banners.objects.filter(id__exact=1)` repeated
for 9 entries in the Model.

My question is that is it possible to split one queryset 
`Banners.objects.all()` into the three groups of three entries and then how would I go about displaying the three groups across three different slides of the Bootstrap Carousel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - queryset split to 4, causes lots of hits to the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029420/django-queryset-split-to-4-causes-lots-of-hits-to-the-database)

Comment: @karthikr, I've tried that solution but it didn't work for me. It created 3 groups of 1 banner each.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place to use the django divisibleby filter.  Since you need to add the extra grouping info every three instances, it could look something like this (very abstractly, since I don't know your specific template demands):

```
{% for banner in banners %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" %}
<!-- your carousel wrapping code here -->
{% endif %}
<!-- code for each individual banners here -->
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" %}
<!-- rest of your carousel wrapping code here -->
{% endif %}
```

where banners would be a context variable that contains `Banners.objects.all()`

Comment: `Banners.objects.all` in a template ??

Comment: Well, no, you'd probably actually want to do it in the view -- but that would technically work if 'Banners' was sent to the template as context.  You can actually access querysets from the template if necessary, but in this case I was just being concise for the sake of keeping the example short.

Comment: That is not right - you cannot do a call to the models directly from django templates - You cannot do it by design. You have to inject it from the context, or use templatetags.

Comment: That is why I said 'send to the template as context' -- but rather than argue I'll just edit the answer.